# I sticked in a step that I could not compelet it

Tags: c

I know the program below is almost wrong and I am seeking for a hep to fix that UP
please help:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>

int i;

float r;

char c;

char s[48];

int main() {

    i=4;

    r=3;

    c='z';
    strcpy(s,"Hi There");

    printf("i=%d,r=%d,c=%d")
}
```

Comment: Is this homework? What is the purpose of this code?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, when you say something is wrong, it might help to point out what it is that is wrong. E.g. add the expected and the actual output, or errors you get when compiling or linking.

Secondly, the error is probably that the `printf` call prints weird values. It's because you tell it to print three values but you don't actually *provide* the values to print. Change to

```
printf("i=%d,r=%d,c=%d", i, r, c);
```

Comment: the string s is missen also google the manpage of your printf. like c should be %c as  it is a char , f should be %f as it is a float and so fourth. be on the look out for a promt of 4 3 z

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int i;
    float r;
    char c;
    char s[48];

    i=4;
    r=3.0;
    c='z';
    strcpy(s,"Hi There");

    printf("i=%d, r=%hf, c=\'%c\', s=\"%s\"", i, r, c, s);

    return 0;
}
```